When David says the Lord is my Shepherd is he expressing joy in his ‘election’ or is he saying the Lord can be your Shepherd too , as is gen accepted
Is what David says evangelistic , is it a call to others .. is he saying the Lord can be your Shepherd .. anyone’s Shepherd .. in that case David isn’t supporting unconditional election because he’s saying anyone can have the Lord as their Shepherd .

Ps 23:1 - A Psalm of David.
The LORD is my shepherd; I shall not want.


"David isn’t supporting unconditional election" — I doubt David had any concept of unconditional election.

But his writing is inspired by the Holy Spirit .. is the Holy Spirit speaking of election or evangelism when David declares publicly The Lord is my Shepherd .. is the Spirit saying to everyone He ( the Lord ) can be your Shepherd too .

Which would deny Unconditional Election .. the U in TULIP in the five points of Calvinism .

When David declares in Psalm 23:1, "The Lord is my shepherd; I shall not want," he is indeed expressing profound joy and gratitude for his divine "election." He sees himself as chosen by God, someone cared for and guided by Him, especially considering the adversities and rejections he faced before being acknowledged as king.
David's life narrative is marked by episodes that reveal this path of election amidst trials and rejection. As a young man, he was called by God while tending sheep, performing a humble and lowly job, as highlighted in Psalm 78:70-72: "He chose David his servant and took him from the sheepfolds; from tending the sheep, he brought him to shepherd his people Jacob." This shepherding role, though often despised, symbolically prepared David for a greater calling: to lead Israel as a shepherd, with trust and dependence on God.
In the emblematic scene of his anointing, David was initially overlooked even by the prophet Samuel. In 1 Samuel 16:11-12, Samuel questions the absence of any more sons of Jesse and stands waiting until David, the youngest, arrives from the fields. Here, God directs the prophet: "Arise, anoint him; for this is he." This unexpected choice underscores David's unique election, emphasizing that God sees beyond human appearances (1 Samuel 16:7).
During the episode with Goliath, David was also disregarded by his own brothers, particularly Eliab, who reprimanded him and tried to discourage him (1 Samuel 17:28). However, David demonstrated courage and faith in God, positioning himself as Israel’s defender and showing his conviction that God had prepared him to conquer even the unimaginable.
Moreover, David was rejected and persecuted by King Saul, who saw him as a threat and treated him as an outlaw. In Psalm 69:4, David laments, "Those who hate me without reason outnumber the hairs of my head; many are my enemies without cause, those who seek to destroy me; I am forced to restore what I did not steal." He sees himself as unjustly persecuted, someone whose character and integrity were misunderstood or ignored.
Thus, Psalm 23 echoes this deep experience of trust in God, coming from a servant who, though unappreciated by people, is carefully chosen and protected by the Lord. The image of the shepherd underscores that, regardless of what others think or do, God is his true guide and provider. It is a personal expression of joy and security, yet, at the same time, this trust in God as Shepherd reflects a relationship that any faithful person could have with the Lord, following the concept of God as the caretaker of His people, a concept expressed since Genesis and throughout Scripture (Genesis 48:15; Isaiah 40:11).
Therefore, Psalm 23 is not merely David’s individual comfort but a testimony of how God is faithful in choosing and caring for those who trust Him, regardless of their initial position or the scorn they may face from people.

Thank you for your answer .. would you say David is also saying ‘The Lord can be your Shepherd too ‘ .. or  does he just want this blessing for  himself  .. consider too that the Holy Spirit has greatly used Psalm 23 to speak to people about God as the Shepherd of their souls ..

Is David being evangelistic .. is he saying all can know the Lord as Shepherd if they would only sincerely come to Him .

Revelation 1:6 "NVI and has made us to be a kingdom and priests to serve his God and Father—to him be glory and power for ever and ever! Amen. " David set an example, yet I don't believe that, at the time, he intended to remove the priestly figure as an intermediary between God and humanity.

In the OT, the LORD acting as Israel's shepherd of both the nation and people individually is a common theme - here is a sample:

Psalm 23:1 - The LORD is my shepherd; I shall not want.
Eze 34:11ff - For this is what the Lord GOD says: ‘Behold, I Myself will search for My flock and seek them out. As a shepherd looks for his scattered sheep when he is among the flock, so I will look for My flock.
Isa 40:11 - He tends His flock like a shepherd; He gathers the lambs in His arms and carries them close to His heart. He gently leads the nursing ewes.
Ps 95:7 - For He is our God, and we are the people of His pasture, the sheep under His care. ...
Ps 100:3 - Know that the LORD is God. It is He who made us, and we are His; we are His people, and the sheep of His pasture.

In the NT, this shepherd of the chosen people is clearly identified as Jesus:

John 10:11-16 - I am the good shepherd. The good shepherd lays down His life for the sheep. The hired hand is not the shepherd, and the sheep are not his own. When he sees the wolf coming, he abandons the sheep and runs away. Then the wolf pounces on them and scatters the flock. The man runs away because he is a hired servant and is unconcerned for the sheep. I am the good shepherd. I know My sheep and My sheep know Me, just as the Father knows Me and I know the Father. And I lay down My life for the sheep. I have other sheep that are not of this fold. I must bring them in as well, and they will listen to My voice. Then there will be one flock and one shepherd.
Heb 13:20 - Now may the God of peace, who through the blood of the eternal covenant brought back from the dead our Lord Jesus, that great Shepherd of the sheep
1 Peter 2:25 - For “you were like sheep going astray,” but now you have returned to the Shepherd and Overseer [Jesus] of your souls.
1 Peter 5:4 - And when the Chief Shepherd [Jesus] appears, you will receive the crown of glory that will never fade away.
Rev 7:17 - For the Lamb in the center of the throne will be their shepherd. ‘He will lead them to springs of living water,’ and ‘God will wipe away every tear from their eyes.’ ”

Now to the specifics of the OP's question about election.  None of these references say anything about the doctrine of election and whether it is universal, or limited, etc.  That information must be drawn from other Bible references.

Thank you for your answer .. is David then in his time .. calling upon others to accept the Lord as their Shepherd .. Psalm 100v3 suggests the writer of the Psalm is leading people to know that the Lord is God .. David seems to be evangelistic in his approach .. saying the Lord is my Shepherd and meaning He can be your Shepherd too ..

Which of course would be contrary to unconditional election because David would be saying all can come and accept the Lord as Shepherd .

@markdanks - agreed. See my answer here about that.
https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/71736/what-does-election-of-grace-mean-in-romans-115/71740#71740
